# WordPress multilingual website domain and folders

Tags: htaccess, domain, plugin-polylang

***Answered & edited !***

I have a single Wordpress installation on **example.com**.

I use Polylang plugin to add multilingual system to this website. I have 16 languages, and it's configured to use **example.com/fr** for French, **example.com/de** for German, etc ...

I want to use domain name for Korean language and Japan. Instead of **example.com/jp**, I want to get the website on **example.jp**.

I'm trying to find a way to do this with .htaccess without moving the others languages on sub domains or domains.

Here is what I have, but if I go to **example.jp/page/** I'm redirected to **example.com/ja/page/**, do you know a way to hide this redirection ?

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.jp$
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/ja/$1 [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Another information if you need, the domain are using CNAME, and I'm on a WP Engine hosting. Concerning permalinks, I'll be able to pass them into a filter to clear the current subdirectory links system.

Thanks for your time !

**EDIT :** 
As explained in the answer, the CNAME and server file system gives me everything I need. I don't need to use .htaccess to achieve what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing you've already updated the internal links and that `example.jp` points to the same place on the filesystem as `example.com` (via CNAME and appropriate server config changes) then you don't necessarily need to *rewrite* to `example.com`, since `example.jp` accesses the same files. Trying to *rewrite* to a different domain will implicitly trigger an external redirect anyway (regardless of whether you specify the `R` flag on the `RewriteRule` directive).

So, to change this to a rewrite on the `example.jp` domain:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.jp
> RewriteRule (.*) /ja/$1 [L]
> ```

(Why are you using `ja` in the *substitution* string - is that a typo? Shouldn't it be `jp` as mentioned earlier in your question?)

However, this may trigger a rewrite-loop, depending on whether you have other directives. So, you would probably need to add a condition to prevent this. For example:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ja/
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.jp
> RewriteRule (.*) /ja/$1 [L]
> ```

The additional `RewriteCond` directive ensures that the requested URL does not (`!` prefix) already start with `/ja/`.

Although it would be more efficient to avoid rewriting `/ja/` URLs with a check in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* instead. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.jp
RewriteRule !^ja/ /ja%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Now, the `RewriteRule` is only processed when the URL does not start `/ja/`, instead of processed *every* request (ie. `.*`).

However, WordPress may still try to canonicalise the hostname? ie. WordPress itself might issue an external redirect to `example.com`. If this is the case then you will need to override this in WordPress or implement a *reverse proxy* using mod_proxy - for which you will ideally have access to the server config.

Comment: Many Thanks for your help. I haven't realize that CNAME already gives me the redirection, I'll probably have to find a way to do it in PHP then. Because you're right : example.jp/ja/mypage gives me the right page. You find the answer without the question ! ("ja" is the language slug)